# Compare Two Objects for Same Properties and Same Property Values

Tags: c#

Is it possible to compare two objects with unknown type and return True if the types are the same and properties are the same else return false ?  I don't want to override Equals as I still want the original comparer "==" to function without any modifications.

The reason for this is I have a collection of objects that I need to get the values for that matches with a single object.  The objects are not necessarily of the same type or the same instance.

```
   ExampleClass
   {
      public string PropertyA {get;set;}
      public string PropertyB {get;set;}
   }

   var a = new ExampleClass() 
   {
      PropertyA = "A",
      PropertyB = "B"
   };

   var b = new ExampleClass() 
   {
      PropertyA = "A",
      PropertyB = "B"
   };

   CheckEqual(a, b);

   bool CheckEqual(object a, object b) 
   {
      //Returns true if object types are the same and properties are the same values
   }
```

Comment: You could do this with reflection, but you're in for some fun if the properties aren't all just value types, as you'd need to also dive into each object property and compare those, and so on (deep compare). Depending on the objects, I might consider cheating by converting them to a serialized format and comparing the value, but that's a performance tradeoff you'd have to be aware of.

Comment: "I don't want to override Equals as I still want the original comparer "==" to function without any modifications" -- overriding `.Equals` does *not* change the semantics of `==`. That would be done separately by implementing `operator==` (which is, of course, recommended if you do have custom rules for equality). Even if you do, `Object.ReferenceEquals` remains available for true instance-based equality.

Comment: A generic "equivalence based comparison" is not easy to write, especially if it has to cover different use cases. You can take a look at how a library like Fluent Assertions does it, and the many options it offers (and if you're doing this in the context of testing I'd recommend you just straight up use Fluent Assertions directly rather than rolling your own).

Comment: @JeroenMostert if that is the case then I might look at overriding Equals.  I read somewhere it overrides == as well

Comment: You don't have to override Equals. You can create a Comparer.

Comment: Also, if you decide to go with Equals, here's a little Learn document that you can do so without it affecting the operator, BUT I think it's discouraged? The Comparer may be a better way to go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

Comment: You could implement `IEquatable<T>` on the class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) or you could create an `IEqualityComparer` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.iequalitycomparer)

Comment: Note that all of the notions of equality .NET has, be they comparers, `==` or `.Equals` overrides work under the assumption that the types of the objects being compared are equal, or at least participate in an inheritance hierarchy. Deviating from this in the cases where you truly need to compare arbitrary objects of different types (and produce anything but `false`) can lead to very hard to debug problems if you end up violating the contracts for equality; in this case you should definitely use dedicated methods that don't attempt to piggyback on these mechanisms.

Comment: @JeroenMostert or there exist implicit conversions between them as in `5 == 5L`.

Comment: If you have the urge to write a reflection based _comparer_, reflect over the type's properties getting the `MethodInfo`s that define the property getters.  Store those in the comparer instance. Also, during your reflection over the properties, look at the type of each property, check that those types either implement `IComparable<T>` or `IEquatable<T>` (if not, give up).  Cache all that info as well.  What you want to do is make your class do all of its heavy reflection work in the constructor (caching the results) and make the class immutable.

Comment: Keeping going... That way, you can create an instance of this for a type and keep it around forever, using it as needed.  You can do this for a single type, but, if you want to be able to do the "by property name/type" for a pair of types, that can work as well.  Just create a `ReflectionBasedComparer<T1, T2>` class and do the same thing as I describe, but keeping track of the property names & types so that you know to compare `PropertyA` of `T1` with `PropertyA` of `T2